# Automatically coming slashes with FileStream in Monodroid

Tags: filestream, xamarin.android

I have been working on a project using Monodroid. I need to use FileStream to access a file in my project. I write the path as a first argument in FileStream like FileStream(path,  FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read) but two slashes come automatically from FileStream, therefore the path is not valid. For example, if the path is "res/raw/aFile.txt", after FileStream method it becomes "//res/raw/aFile.txt" and an exception occurs. Because of the exception, I cannot split and get the valid path. How can I get rid of the two slashes that automatically coming from the FileStream method?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to open a raw resource file, I would suggest using the [OpenRawResource()](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=M%3aAndroid.Content.Res.Resources.OpenRawResource%28System.Int32%29) method instead:

```
using (var stream = Resources.OpenRawResource(Resource.Raw.File))
{
}
```

Comment: I know the way you talk about. But for the rest of my code, I must use FileStream way. My problem is just the slashes.